# How to see time taken by each method in Java program during execution

Tags: java, optimization, profiler

I am trying to find the time taken by each method that my Java program calls, while executing. I do not want to litter my code with `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Maybe, something like a profiler or an IDE plugin, but I am not sure if that is what it is called. Can someone help me by pointing me in the right direction?

**Sample code** :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   Obj A = new Obj();
   ObjDiff B = new ObjDiff();
   A.callMe();
   B.callMeToo();
}
```

**Tools/Frameworks** :

- Eclipse
- Struts

**What I Want** :

1. Time taken to instantiate `Obj A`,
2. Time taken to instantiate `ObjDiff B`,
3. Time taken to run `A.callMe()`,
4. Time taken to run `B.callMeToo()`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Rohitesh

**EDIT** :
I have installed VisualVM and used it as a standalone app. It has been helpful. However, my primary concern is still not addressed. I cannot look at the memory/CPU usage, method wise. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: VisualVM, check it out.  http://visualvm.java.net/

Comment: Check out AspectJ from Spring

Comment: There are many performance monitoring tools like JMON you can use them to get the time taken by each statement.

Comment: I second sanbhat, try AOP.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) too, basic but quite useful. Recommended you run it on the same Java 7 JVM as your app top avoid compatibility issues. If you need more advanced features like tracing a user interaction with a web server, you can look at more elaborate profilers like Introscope.

Comment: Not to mention VirtualVM is free! :)

Comment: typo, it is VisualVM, not virtualVM.

Answer (score 2):

VisualVM is a good tool.
My favortine one (by far) is JProfiler. It is not free and quite expensive if you're not a company but you can evaluate it for 10 days.